# Accessing mobx observable property in React Component in Jest unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mobx

Below is my component. The mobx state is just in the body of the component, I don't create a separate store for it.

My question is how to access those mobx state variables within jest/enzyme unit tests?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BookIcon } from 'react-octicons-svg';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';


@observer
class Wallet extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        name: React.PropTypes.string,
        wallet: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

   @observable showPassbook = false;
   @observable wallet = Object.assign({}, this.props.wallet);

    render() {

        const walletTitle = this.wallet.title || this.wallet.wallet_name || this.props.name || "no name";

        return (<div>
                <h2>Wallet for {walletTitle}</h2>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md">
                        <ul className="list-unstyled mt-2">
                            <li><strong>Balance:</strong> {formatNumber(Number(this.wallet.balance.amount), this.wallet.balance.currency)} {this.wallet.balance.currency}</li>
                            <li><strong>State:</strong> {this.wallet.state}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>      
                </div>


                <div> 
                    <button className="btn-link" title="Show Passbook" onClick={() => { this.showPassbook = true; }}><BookIcon /> Show Passbook</button>
                   </div>
                {this.showPassbook && (<div>Passbook</div>)}    
            </div>
        )}
};

export default Wallet;
```

The relevant part of my Jest unit test is:

```
it("button to get passbook", function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Wallet name="carlos" wallet={walletData}/>)
    console.log("showpassbook", this.showPassbook);
  })
```

How can I get access to mobx observable properties within my unit tests?
Currently this.showPassbook or wrapper.showPassbook are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [**instance**](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) of the wrapper and access the field:

```
it("button to get passbook", function() {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Wallet name="carlos" wallet={walletData}/>)
  console.log("showpassbook", wrapper.instance().showPassbook);
})
```

Comment: could I use wrapper.instance().showPassbook = true in my test to change the value of showPassbook in the component? Something renders conditionally if showPassbook is true. I want to test that.

Comment: @criver.to I don't know, I'm afraid.